# How i can change bootstrap navbar hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i edit this to be able to see the navbar options. Currently it has the same color as background.I want to change the font before to white and change them when it hover to white background with blue color font.

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="tog" style="padding-top:7px; ">
        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="menu-toggle"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> 
        </a>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="top-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-bell"> </span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle profile-image" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" class="img-circle special-img">xxx <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign-out</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to your downloaded bootstrap.css file and makes the changes  maybe somewhere around line 4489..

change the css of this selector

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: whilst this works - it alters the base CSS of Bootstrap. A fact that you may not remember in time when you want a different effect or to remove the effect all together. Far better would be to add a CSS rule to your own style sheet and load it AFTER loading the Bootstrap one so that it takes precedence. IMO :))

Comment: sometimes it is not possible to override bootstrap CSS and this is left as the only solution in that case..